# Welcher Fall soll in diesem Satz nach „als“ stehen?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, grammaticality, apposition

Heute morgen bin ich folgendem Satz begegnet:

> Im eher als schönen Sprache geltenden Italienisch nutzt man vor allem Vokale und nur wenige exotische Laute.*

Meine Frage bezieht sich auf die durch *im* eingeleitete Präpositionalgruppe. Welcher Fall wäre nach *als* denn richtig? Ich habe einem Deutschmuttersprachler die Frage gestellt, der meinte, es sollte *im eher als schöne Sprache geltenden Italienisch* heißen (also Nominativ). Ich kann das gut nachvollziehen wegen der aktuellen Tendenz, immer nach *als* den Nominativ zu verwenden, egal in welchem Fall das Bezugswort steht.

Ich könnte es auch verstehen, wenn man meinte, Bezugswort und Anschluss müssten immer gleich dekliniert werden. Da das Bezugswort (*Italienisch*) im Dativ stehen muss, würde der Satzteil lauten:

> Im eher als schöne*r* Sprache geltenden Italienisch…

Aber vielleicht wirkt das auf Deutsche sehr unnatürlich oder sogar falsch.

Ich konnte auch gar keine Klarheit darüber schaffen, woher dieses *schönen* im Originalsatz kommt. Könnte mir irgendjemand erklären, was genau mit diesem Satz los ist?

<sub>* Hier ist die [Quelle](http://y2u.be/l-v_SJzJQNw#t=2m27s), falls ihr euch selbst den Satz anhören möchtet. Es mag sein, dass ich einfach den Sprecher missverstanden habe. Aber mit Kopfhörern ist – glaube ich – die Form *schönen* deutlich zu hören.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich höre in dem Youtube-Video klar "Im eher als schöne Sprache geltenden Italienisch ...". Die automatischen Untertitel liegen hier nach meinem Gehör falsch.

<s>"Als schönen Sprache"</s> wäre auch nicht richtig, weil *die Sprache* weiblich ist, dazu könnte "schönen" überhaupt nicht passen, bzw. nur mit einem zusätzlichen Artikel (z.B. *einer schönen Sprache*, Dativ/Genitiv).

Beim Kasus, der hinter *als* steht, muss man hier berücksichtigen, dass das "als" hier von "geltenden" abhängt, der Teil "als ... geltenden" bildet eine Partizipialphrase. In diesem Fall hängt der Kasus nur noch von der Rolle des Satzteils innerhalb der Partizipphrase ab, und nicht mehr vom Satzzusammenhang, in dem die Partizipphrase im Satz steht.

Man kann so etwas prüfen, indem man die Partizipphrase in einen Hauptsatz umwandelt:

> Italienisch gilt als schöne Sprache.

Da in diesem Satz "schöne Sprache" im Nominativ steht, gilt das auch in der Partizipphrase. (Duden-Grammatik Abschnitt 1549).

Ohne "geltend" - der Dativ von "im Italienischen" wird übernommen:

> Im Italienischen als besonders schöner europäischer Sprache nutzt man vor allem Vokale ...

> Im Italienischen als einer besonders schönen europäischen Sprache nutzt man vor allem Vokale ...

Mit "geltend" - der Dativ wird nicht übernommen, sondern der Nominativ benutzt:

> Im als besonders schöne europäische Sprache geltenden Italienischen nutzt man vor allem Vokale ...

Comment: Danke für die Antwort, das hilft mir weiter. Ich habe auch gerade gesehen, dass einige verwandte Sätze im 2010 erschienenen Band *The Syntax of German* von Hubert Haider stehen, z. B. *Er erkannte den als kreativer Syntaktiker sehr bekannten Professor/den ein kreaktiver Syntaktiker bleiben wollenden Professor.* In solchen Fällen ist ja nur Nominativ nach *als* möglich. Haider gibt noch dazu genaue Grundregeln an, von denen sich der richtige Fall ableiten lässt (S. 265).

Answer (score -2):

I would say "*Im eher als schöne**r** Sprache geltenden Italienisch*" is the only correct declination in this case (In case *decination* applies here).
Maybe due to one of the "Rechtschreibreform" omitting the 'r' is considered correct as well, but to me, it sounds faulty.

Comment: Could you explain why it should be Dativ in your opinion? To me that's incorrect because of the word "geltenden". Would you also say: "Italienisch gilt als schöner Sprache" (instead of "als schöne Sprache", Nominativ)? Or "Trotz eines als Weihnachtsmannes verkleideten Onkels ..." (instead of: "trotz eines als Weihnachtsmann verkleideten Onkels" (Nominativ))? I don't get your reasoning here. Also, this is grammar, nothing changed about this with Rechtschreibreform.

Comment: Of course I would say as a native German '"Italienisch gilt als schöne Sprache' I would also say "Das als schöne Sprache geltende Italienisch", but due to the **Im**' introducing the whole expression, a **Dativ** construction is required, and without any article **schön** gets declined to **schöner** which is the Dativ femininum without any article. See Example with Katze, hiere: https://sprachekulturkommunikation.com/deutsch-lernen-adjektivdeklination-ohne-artikel/
Your example with 'Weihnachtsmannes' does not make sense because it is Genetiv. And schöner in the former example is Dativ.

Comment: So you're arguing that because of "im" it has to be Dativ, but it's a whole different thing with "trotz" and Genitiv? Why? I looked it up in Duden Grammatik in the meantime. Since "Italienisch gilt als schöne Sprache" uses the nominative, the participle phrase "als schöne Sprache geltend" also needs Nominativ after als, regardless of the case in the surrounding sentence, as explained in my answer. It's the same with "Der Onkel ist als Weihnachtsmann verkleidet" => "Trotz des als Weihnachtsmann verkleideten Onkels..."

Comment: Despite the fact your deductive explanations sound reasonable I'm still fully convinced the only correct+more over elaborate expression is "Im eher als schöner Sprache geltenden Italienisch". "Im eher als schöne Sprache geltenden Italienisch" sounds a little clumsy and funny, least to my ear.
Same is true e.g. for "Er erkannte den als kreativer Syntaktiker sehr bekannten Professor" some prof claims to be good/correct German. Sounds like a horrible phonetic, grammerly accident. Should be "als kreativen Syntaktiker". The birth defect here is to squeeze language into rules it wasn't built from.

Comment: Well, you see, to me, "Im eher als schöner Sprache geltenden Italienisch" sounded dead wrong from the beginning and still does, and I think you've just gone deep down the wrong rabbit hole here. So as long as you don't show some Thomas Mann or Hesse or Kant or, really, any examples from credible sources, I will continue to just think you're completely mislead here.

Comment: I don't mind if you keep thinking your sense of correctly phrasing the subject of Italian language beauty is correct+the rabbit hole you've run into is the only true and correct rabbit hole ever ;). But it is just because I've read some dozens books of Hesse, Mann, Max Frisch, Thomas Bernhard, etc that I am convinced that the version I mentioned is right. I have to disappoint you nonetheless, I won't start reading these books again just to proof I am right. In case I will stumble accidently over an example concerning this subject by one of the authors, I'll add it to this conversation. Bye :)

Comment: This has a lot time, no problem. I'm just saying that your only source so far has been your Sprachgefühl and you have shown *nothing at all* to support your argument.